# Ajuda na logica de programação de string?

Tags: c

Sou novo nessa area de string e estou com dificulade. Meu algoritmo deve encontrar e retornar o ındice da primeira ocorrencia
da chave(que o usuario digitar) na string, caso contrario deve-se retornar -1. O q ta errado na minha funcao?

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <math.h>  
#define MAX 100  

int str_length(char str[])    
{  
    int i =0;  

    while(str[i]!='\0')  
    {  
        i++;  
    }  

    return i;
}

int str_chave(char str[], int comp)
{
    int i=0;
    char chave;

    printf("Informe um caractere: ");
    scanf("%s",&chave);

    for (comp; str[i] != chave; comp--)
    {

        if(str[i]==chave)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        str[i]--;

    }
return 0;

}

int main()  
{  
    char string[MAX];  
    int comp,res,resi,chave;
    long long int n;
    long long int number;

    printf("Digite uma string: ");
    scanf("%[^\n]s",string);

    comp = str_length(string);

    printf("Comprimento de '%s': %d\n",string,comp);

     chave=str_chave(string,comp);
        if(chave==0)
            printf("O caractere informado existe na string.\n");
        else
            printf("O caractere informado nao existe na string.\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ta retornando algum erro?

Comment: @rLinhares nao esta, mas se eu digitar por exemplo 'oi' e informa chave como 'k', ele fala q esta dentro da string, ta informando sempre q esta para qlqr chave q informo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tem vários pequenos erros no seu programa:

- O `if` para mostrar o resultado está trocado:

  ```
  if(chave==0)
      printf("O caractere informado existe na string.\n");
  else
      printf("O caractere informado nao existe na string.\n");
  ```

  O retorno que sai da função é `0` quando não existe, mas no `if` o `0` escreve que "O caractere informado existe na string", e por isso deve trocar os dois `printfs`.
- A leitura do caratere a procurar não está correta:

  ```
  printf("Informe um caractere: ");
  scanf("%s",&chave);
  ```

  Se é um caratere deve ser lido com `%c`, caso contrário o programa vai tentar colocar o terminador `\0` devido a ser `string` e vai faze-lo num espaço de memória que não lhe pertence, criando um bug subtil, que pode surgir mais à frente.

  Ao trocar para `%c` vai lhe criar outro problema em relação à leitura anterior de `scanf("%[^\n]s"` pois a quebra de linha em si não foi consumida. Para resolver os dois sem complicar pode fazer assim:

  ```
  scanf(" %c",&chave);
  ```

  Em que o espaço consome a quebra de linha anterior.
- O `for` para procura do caratere também não está correto:

  ```
  for (comp; str[i] != chave; comp--)
  {
      if(str[i]==chave)
      {
          return 1;
      }
     str[i]--;
  }
  ```

  Aqui o inicio de `(comp;` é redudante e não faz nada, logo pode remove-lo. Depois se utiliza o `i` para aceder à posição e buscar a letra então o `i` tem de aumentar e não o `comp` diminuir. Para alem disso não está a considerar o caso em que não encontra a letra na condição de fim `str[i] != chave` que lhe pode deixar percorrendo a memoria infinitamente.

  Correto seria:

  ```
  for (; i < comp; i++) {
      if(str[i] == chave) {
          return 1;
      }
  }
  ```

  Que fica até mais simples.

[Veja o seu código corrigido a funcionar no Ideone](https://ideone.com/vc6jDM)

### Reinventar a roda

Eu sei que em C muitas vezes temos de facto que reinventar a roda, mas no seu caso está a faze-lo mais do que seria necessário, e a menos que seja para fins educativos deve de o evitar.

- `str_length` - Já existe uma função nativa para obter o tamanho da `string` chamada [`strlen`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strlen/),
- Toda a lógica que o seu programa está a tentar fazer de achar a primeira ocorrência numa string já existe na função [`strstr`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strstr/)

Para utilizar as duas funções que indiquei precisa de incluir `<string.h>`, mas o seu programa fica muito mais curto e simples:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> //nova inclusão aqui
#define MAX 100

int main() {
    char string[MAX];
    printf("Digite uma string: ");
    scanf("%[^\n]s",string);
    int comp = strlen(string); //comprimento com strlen
    printf("Comprimento de '%s': %d\n", string, comp);

    printf("Informe um caractere: ");
    char chave[2];
    scanf("%s",chave); //leitura como string pois é necessário para o strstr

    if(!strstr(string, chave)) //achar ocorrencia com strstr
        printf("O caractere informado nao existe na string.\n");
    else
        printf("O caractere informado existe na string.\n");

    return 0;
}
```

[Veja também este exemplo no Ideone](https://ideone.com/mpT6oU)

Comment: Muito boa resposta

Comment: Obrigado pela dicas de funcoes que a bilbioteca string.h tem, mas nao posos usar nenhuma kkk. Preciso fazer uma logica sem utilizar essa funcoes da biblioteca, mas vlw ai pelas dicas

Answer (score 1):

Você pode simplificar a busca na função `str_chave` usando a variável `i` para controlar a posição sendo buscada, e retornar ela quando encontrar. Por exemplo:

```
for (i; i < comp; i++)
{
    if(str[i]==chave)
    {
        return i+1; //O indice comeca em 0, mas queremos a posicao com base 1
    }
}
return 0;
```

Feito isso, basta alterar para mostrar o indice retornado em tela:

```
if(chave==0)
    printf("O caractere informado nao existe na string\n");
else
    printf("O caractere informado existe na string, posicao: %d.\n", chave);
```

Comment: deu certo, obrigado mano, coisa simples de se fzr e eu aqui quebrando a cabeca kkkkk

Answer (score 0):

Como é um único caractere troque:

```
 scanf("%s",&chave);
```

por:

```
 scanf("%c", &chave);
```

Note que você terá problemas se a chave não existir na string e também existe uma confusão entre a variável i e a variável comp.

Comment: eu troquei, mas agora n ta deixando nem eu informar a 'chave', melhor eu deixar o %s mesmo.

Comment: Creio que é melhor você estudar o significado de %s e %c na função scanf. Você também alterou a definição de chave de char (um caractere) para uma string de 2 posições, neste caso não poderá utilizar o operador == para igualdade.